# Is Gradient Accumulation equivalent to using larger batch sizes?

Tags: neural-networks, gradient

Gradient accumulation is used to deal with memory limitation by partitioning a large batch size into small chunks. For example, instead of using a batch size of 1024 samples per batch you could use 256 samples and accumulate gradients four times.

However, are these two actually equivalent? If I kept all things the same, will accumulating gradients give me the same gradients if I had instead used the larger batch size? If not, are there ultimately any differences between the two in final testing performance or convergence time?

I tried to test this with a very small network ( about a dozen trainable parameters), and did not get the same gradients - however, my implementation to keep everything deterministic could have been incorrect.

Also, if gradient accumulation is different in performance from using a larger batch size, are there better alternatives?